# Django Heroku Migrate Error(?): "You have 21 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s)"

Tags: python, django, heroku, localhost, hosting

So I'm working on hosting a project and on my Heroku dashboard it says it's live, but every time I try to access it I get a 500 Server Error, even when trying to access it locally via Heroku CLI.

I tried running migrations because I get the following warning:

> You have 21 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, recipe, sessions, users.
> Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Even after running makemigrations and migrate, as can be seen in screenshot below, any suggestions to what I might be missing?

```
C:\Users\davba\OneDrive\Documents\David\CSC-456\LIA_Project\Leftover-Ingredients->heroku run -a fathomless-cliffs-95117 python manage.py makemigrations
Running python manage.py makemigrations on ⬢ fathomless-cliffs-95117... up, run.3466 (Free)
No changes detected

C:\Users\davba\OneDrive\Documents\David\CSC-456\LIA_Project\Leftover-Ingredients->heroku run -a fathomless-cliffs-95117 python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ fathomless-cliffs-95117... up, run.3409 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, recipe, sessions, users
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying recipe.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying users.0001_initial... OK
  Applying users.0002_alter_profile_image... OK

C:\Users\davba\OneDrive\Documents\David\CSC-456\LIA_Project\Leftover-Ingredients->heroku run -a fathomless-cliffs-95117 python manage.py runserver
Running python manage.py runserver on ⬢ fathomless-cliffs-95117... up, run.6946 (Free)
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 21 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, recipe, sessions, users.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
November 17, 2021 - 00:20:55
Django version 3.2.8, using settings 'LeftoverIngredients.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: Let me guess: you're using SQLite? You can't use SQLite on Heroku.

Comment: where you have deployed your database

Comment: Database was originally SQLite, then after reading the above comment I changed it for postgresql from Heroku, so it’s deployed on Heroku and still get the same error